# qTips JS script from JS Fiddle Doesn't Work

Tags: jquery-tooltip

I am trying to implement the following qTip tooltip script on my page:

```
// Create the tooltips only when document ready
$(document).ready(function()
{
  // MAKE SURE YOUR SELECTOR MATCHES SOMETHING IN YOUR HTML!!!
  $('a').each(function() {
     $(this).qtip({
         content: {
             text: $(this).next('.tooltiptext')
         }
     });
 });
});
```

I got the script directly from the [JS Fiddle documentation page](http://jsfiddle.net/craga89/G2sqU/), but unfortunately, the script doesn't work on JS Fiddle either.  I am sure there is a typo somewhere in this, but I don't have the JS skills to find it.

Can someone help me to correct this script?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

I like qTip2 but the one thing that I hate about it is that its documentation blows. The creator gives sample code but omits certain necessary parts of it which makes it confusing. He also includes *broken fiddles* like the one you gave above.

Not to mention, that fiddle is unnecessarily complicated if he is just displaying one tooltip.

I created a very basic example of a qTip2 at the link here: http://jsfiddle.net/ah653at2/1/

I hope you can use this instead to gain a basic understanding of the library.

**HTML:**

```
<a id="test">A very basic tooltip example</a>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
$("#test").qtip({
    content: {
        text: 'This is some tooltip content',
    },
});
```